# Why Internet marketer using same format on their website?

Tags: css, xhtml, web

I wonder why most of marketing site will use same format? Example

- [Learn PHP by Yourself In 11 Hours](http://www.phpyourself.com/)
- [Spice up Your Site With Simple PHP](http://www.simplephp.com/)
- and much more..

This is a standard design for web designing on site like this?

---

May admin move my question to another network which related to my question?

Comment: This is not a question about programming.

Comment: @James The question is: "Why there's that common factor (Identical Page Design / Structure) across differents marketing sites?" - Another really good question wuold be "Why they use such horrible design/structure?"

Comment: the code standard is called "ugly".

Comment: Sorry.. Should I write code on every my questions? I just want to know that design is code standard for type of website like that. Let me know if I'm asked wrong question here :)

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming, not design. Please clarify your question. Are you interested in why the sites are designed this way? - your question will probably be moved to another SE site. Are you interested in why the sites use some specific coding/CSS style? - please clarify what you want to know.

Comment: "PHP yourself"? Seriously? Who comes up with those names? Makes me want to reply to the page's author "and PHP you, too" ;)

Comment: May admin move my question to another network which related to my question?

Comment: @user700515: I don't think there *is* a site for that. You could just as well have asked "why do people like Comic Sans?" - unless you ask those who use it, there's no way to tell (and then I'd suspect the answer to be "oh, I dunno").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "style" comes from treating a webpage as if it were a printed page, such as a piece of junk mail, which is what these sites strongly resemble. It is used by marketroids who care nothing for the medium as long as they get the "buy" message across to as many stupid people as possible. No coder with a conscience, or even a sense of style, would do this.

Comment: But... but.... *Learn PHP yourself!* No more expensive programmers! For just $39.95!

Comment: @Pekka: Also, "Sleep till noon"! That would explain my propensity to oversleep since I started with PHP. "New research! Scientists say PHP makes you sleepy!"

Comment: @Piskvor oh boy! That's another great feature. That pushes it over the top: What we have here is **incredible** value for money.